# Stretch image in <picture> element within diashow

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, splidejs

I have a  element with given sources for different devices.
I can not style them properly so that the images stretch to fill the container, which results in whitespaces on bigger screens like the iPhone 12 pro Max.

How can I style the `<source>` element within a `<picture>` element to be `width: 100%, height: 100%;` ?

I already tried setting  to `display:flex;` which should be the equivalent to `object-fit: cover;` but it does not work.

Below you see the different results on the devices. On the first picture, there remains whitespace on the right (iPhone 12 Pro Max). On the second picture the image is fully stretched to the viewport (iPhone 6/7/8) .

[image: iPhone 12 pro Max]
[image: iphone 6/7/8]

***UPDATE***

This is my HTML markup, basically 3 picture elements in a splide slideshow.

```
<div class="heroHomepageSection">
<div id="image-slider" class="splide">
    <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
            <li class="splide__slide">

                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 750px)" srcset="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/inc/images/IMG_8792-min.JPG">
                    <source srcset="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/inc/images/mobilePicture.png">
                    <img src="art-direction-vertical.jpg" alt="">
                </picture>

            </li>

            <li class="splide__slide">

                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 750px)" srcset="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/inc/images/IMG_8801-min.JPG">
                    <source srcset="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/inc/images/mobilePicture4.png">
                    <img src="art-direction-vertical.jpg" alt="">
                </picture>

            </li>

            <li class="splide__slide">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 750px)" srcset="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/inc/images/IMG_8793-min.JPG">
                    <source srcset="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/inc/images/mobilePicture3.png">
                    <img src="art-direction-vertical.jpg" alt="">
                </picture>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css that I added so far.

```
.splide__list picture{
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Everything else is set by the splide library and it works perfect on desktop.
You can visit the website aswell here: https://easy-loft.de

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please add your HTML markup and CSS

Comment: using the mobile devices emulator in Chrome things look OK until landscape orientation is chosen. Is that the same effect you describe but on a greater scale? With the blue overlay it is hard to tell

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes it looks Ok, until you try it on bigger devices. Try 428x926px for example, which is equivalent to an iphone 12 pro Max. There appears a whitespace on the right...